# Add an empty assoc array to array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `$inputArray` which I order based on `$arraySort`, but in the loop I like to add an empty assoc array if the `$key` exist in `$arraySort` but not in `$inputArray`

My input array looks something like this

```
    Array
(
    [period2] => Array
        (
            [art] => 171
            [design] => 167
            [math] => 155
            [bio] => 177
        )

    [period1] => Array
        (
            [art] => 194
            [design] => 188
            [math] => 187
            [bio] => 191
        )

    [period3] => Array
        (
            [art] => 182
            [design] => 173
            [math] => 174
            [bio] => 172
        )
)
```

I order my $inputArray with

```
  $arraySort = ['period1', 'period2', 'Break', 'period3'];
                $final_array = [];
                foreach ($arraySort as $arraySo) {
 if(array_key_exists($arraySo, $output)){
                    echo 'found';
                } else {
                    echo 'not found';//here empty assoc array??
                }
                    $final_array[$arraySo] = $output[$arraySo];
                }
                $temp = $final_array;
```

At the moment my output is

```
[period1] => Array
            (
                [art] => 194
                [design] => 188
                [math] => 187
                [bio] => 191
            )

        [period2] => Array
            (
                [art] => 171
                [design] => 167
                [math] => 155
                [bio] => 177
            )

        [Break] => 
        [period3] => Array
            (
                [art] => 198
                [design] => 192
                [math] => 197
                [bio] => 191
            )
```

But I like to add an empty assoc array so break looks like

```
[Break] => Array
            (
                [art] => 0
                [design] => 0
                [math] => 0
                [bio] => 0
        )
```

Comment: The desired operation of your script isn't enough clear, but my answer can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple write:

```
$finalArray['Break'] => Array
(
    ['art'] => 0
    ['design'] => 0
    ['math'] => 0
    ['bio'] => 0
)
```

Comment: Your single quote runned out from square bracket :)

Comment: Yes, that bad single quote! :) thk's

Comment: Indeed. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($output[$arraySo]) &&  is_array($output[$arraySo]) ) {
$final_array[$arraySo] = $output[$arraySo];
} else {
$finalArray[$arraySo] => Array
(
    ['art'] => 0
    ['design'] => 0
    ['math'] => 0
    ['bio'] => 0
)
}
```

Comment: Always add explanations to your answers as there might be newbies on here that does not know how this solution might or might not solve the problem. Always be clear on both questions and answers.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.